# How to style the tooltips in qtip2 as in the qtip1 default?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip, qtip2

How to style the tooltips in qtip2 as in the qtip1 default?

I liked the qtip1 default styling, but when I upgraded I lost it.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read on the [Homepage](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) he redesigned the library from scratch. Now you have to include a CSS. So you can use the [Converter](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/converter/) to convert your style.

If this does not solve your styling problem, please describe the points here and perhaps we can help you. You can also read more in the [Documentation Style Guide](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/style/) or some [Styling Tutorials](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/styling/)